# Opening Godot documentation when the caret is on an engine-related keyword

Tags: godot-4

In Godot 3.x, pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut while the blinking text cursor is on an engine-related keyword (methods, properties, etc.) will open the in-editor documentation window at the page related to such keyword.

This desirable behaviour allows me to move the text cursor on a keyword in a script, e.g. `_process`, and the documentation will show up on the right page after pressing the Help shortcut.

However, Godot 4.x doesn't behave this way. Pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> will open the *Search Help* window regardless of what text is currently selected in a script, prompting me to input the search terms for its documentation.

Is this the new state of things, or can I customise this behaviour and switch back to the previous functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the documentation of the engine-related keywords, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> (Left Mouse Button) on the desired keyword. It's that what you mean?

Comment: This is _exactly_ the behaviour I was expecting! Oddly, I use the same shortcut when working in VS Code but didn't think of it when trying to do the same in Godot! 

Answer (score 1):

The *Contextual Help* hotkey might be what you're looking for.

On Windows / Linux press <kbd>Alt + F1</kbd>. 
On Mac press <kbd>Alt + Shift + Space</kbd>.

I'm running 3.5.1 & for me, the contextual help behaves as you describe for built in Godot methods & properties & the same hot key is listed in the [stable (4.1) hotkey listing](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/default_key_mapping.html). Oddly when I try just using <kbd>F1</kbd> by itself in 3.5.1 it brings up the help search but doesn't fill the search in for me as you described in your 3.x experience.

Comment: I'm on v4.1 on Linux, but the `Alt+F1` combo opens the Search Help window and fills the search bar with the string the caret is currently on, requiring me to actually click on a valid search result. No contextual help, though. OTOH, when using v3.4, I downloaded Godot from a different package manager, and some shortcuts may have been slightly changed, as the `F1` shortcut opened contextual help as I described.